# using async await with redux reducer

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, async-await

What's wrong with below code? I got async is a reserved word error, I have babel configured for async/await.

```
export async function getCredit(){
  return dispatch => {
    try {
      const creditInfo = await axios.get(`/credit`)
    } catch (err) {
      dispatch(errorMsg(err.data.msg))
    }

    if(creditInfo.result === 200 && res.data.status === 1) {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_CREDIT,
        payload: creditInfo.data
      })
    }
  }
}
```

I even tried this

```
export async getCredit() => dispatch => {
  try {
    const creditInfo = await axios.get(`/credit`)
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch(errorMsg(err.data.msg))
  }

  if(creditInfo.result === 200 && res.data.status === 1) {
    dispatch({
      type: GET_CREDIT,
      payload: creditInfo.data
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a higher order function (a function that returns a function), you should add `async` to the nested function where `await` is used instead of the outer function (which merely returns a function).

```
export function getCredit(){
  return async dispatch => {
```

Comment: I see, but can't I get rid of the `function` word and use arrow function instead?

Comment: You can, I'm just following your first code snippet. Replace first line with `export const getCredit = () => {`

Comment: You can also shorten the 2 lines to `export const getCredit = () => async dispatch => {`